# What does M^L represent over this Sigma?

Tags: time-series, time, information

[image]

This is throwing me for a loop. in regards to this passage, does the M^L represent to perform this sum over every "overlapping window" individually? Would this mean "M symbols" are the unique symbols to that specific window?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question does not belong to quant SE.

Comment: @Kermittfrog The original article is exploring entropy evolution of foreign exchange rates during financial crises (*here is a [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378437115011619#!)*). I can understand the confusion, since this is not visible in the above picture. Hence, the question is about a statistical methodology which is used within the area of finance.  I think this needs to be considered before closing the question :-).

Comment: My first take of how it works (needs to be checked and corrected by careful reading and re-reading of the article).The exchange rates are "quantized" into discrete ranges and encoded into symbols (EURUSD between 1.0 and 1.1 is "F", between 1.1 and 1.2 "G", etc.). Over a specific time frame (december 12 2021 to december ... 2021) the evolution of the exchange rate produces a "word" such as "FGFEFEGF" and this word contains a sequence of length L=8 symbols and contains M=3 distinct symbols namely E,F,G.  As time moves on, we drop the oldest (leftmost) symbol and add a new symbol on the right.

Comment: Could you rephrase the final paragraph, your first phrase is not quite clear.